# Variables in Django template are showing in double quotes

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I fetch the data from my `Post` model and simply passed into the template. But the output is showing in double quotes.
I have html tags in my Post model, which is not rendering but showing as codes.

> views.py

```
# It display the single post
def single_post(request,cat,post_id,post_title):
    single_post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/single_post.html', {'single_post': single_post})
```

---

> single_post.html

```
<h1>I'm single post page</h1>

{{single_post.title}}

<br>
<br>
{{single_post.content}}
```

---

> Browser Output

[image]
[image]

> Data in my Database
>   [image]

Comment: Were the screen shots changed? They don't seem to match with the answer from shacker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your screenshot, I do not see double quotes, I see HTML tags. If you are entering HTML into the content, rather than letting untrusted users enter it, then you should consider it safe for rendering onto the page (you're not likely to post malicious javascript, or to screw up your layout with bad HTML, right?). Therefore you want to use Django's `safe` filter on your content:

```
{{single_post.content|safe}}
```

That will allow the entered and stored  HTML to be interpreted, rather than rendered.

Comment: Can you add screenshots to your OP showing what data is stored in the db (as shown in Django Admin) and where the double quotes appear on the page?

Comment: Your IBB screenshot shows quotes in the DOM - this is normal. If you have a problem with double quotes on the final  displayed page, show that. From what you've posted, the only real problem is HTML tags being displayed.

Comment: Please show the page as displayed to the end user, showing the double quotes problem.

Comment: I think my problem is solved. Maybe in the browser double quotes are always there in paragraph. I just saw the content of some other site and the double quotes also there. I think I never had any problem, it is usual to have double quotes in the black text in browser (in the browser codes)

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying - if you view via "Inspect Source" you are looking at the DOM, *not* the HTML source (for that, do View Source - they're different in many ways). Strings are quoted in the DOM view.

Comment: I am in web development from long time. Today in my life I come to know. Thanks again.